# SELECT JOIN MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables which is `user`and `userdata`.

Once a customer buy a product, it will insert into table `userdata` and `user`.

In `user` table , the product id is recorded in `user`.`buyid` in form of "id, id ,id ,id ,id".

example : "23, 24". So I have tried to get all rows with id ( 23, 24 ) from product by using these queries

```
SELECT * FROM `userdata`,`user` WHERE `userdata`.`id` IN (`user`.`buyid`);
```

Query return 1 row product which is id=23

```
SELECT * FROM `user` INNER JOIN `userdata` ON `userdata`.`id` IN (`user`.`buyid`);
```

This too return only 1 row of product with id 23.

Expected result each row return this:

```
user.id | user.name | user.contact | product.id | product.name
1       | nazmi     | 99999        | 23         | A
1       | nazmi     | 99999        | 24         | B
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result as formatted text (not as images.)

Comment: Are you storing data as comma separated items?!? That will only cause you lots of trouble...

Comment: `IN (\`user\`.\`buyid\`)` won't work with a string that is a comma separated list. It's still a string -- one value. Don't store the products in a comma separated list. Have a linking table storing one row consisting of the user ID and the product ID for each product a user bought.

Comment: If you are storing data as comma seperated items please read up on [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @stickybit how do i store in different table as the user is randomly(without login) so i could not synchronize userid on both table, could you help me in this. Thank you

Comment: How do you know which user it is now?

Comment: @stickybit by storing the product id  in the user table.Meanwhile product id is unique.

Comment: @jarlh updated question

Comment: Yeah, but if you store it in the user table, you need to know for which user you store it there, don't you?

Comment: @stickybit i think i get an idea by using POST and update the product table with collumn issuer_id by getting their contact in user table since id is random.. is that okay

Answer (score 1):

Fix your data model!  Storing lists of ids in a string is bad, bad, bad:

- Your id is an integer.  It should be stored as a number, not a string.
- Your id refers to another table.  It should have properly declared foreign key relationships.
- A column should contain a single column.
- SQL has a great way of storing lists.  Really powerful. It is called a "table" not a "string column".
- String processing capabilities are pretty poor in SQL.
- Queries with such data structures cannot take advantage of indexes and partitioning.

Sometimes, you are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad decisions.  MySQL offers a nice function (too nice in my opinion) to help:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u JOIN
     userdata ud
     ON find_in_set(ud.id, u.buyid) > 0;
```

If you have spaces in your id list, then you need to get rid of them.  And the separator has to be a comma.

```
SELECT *
FROM user u JOIN
     userdata ud
     ON find_in_set(ud.id, replace(u.buyid, ' ', '')) > 0;
```

Comment: im sorry , it still return 1 row